# Move data from SQL results to existing table

Tags: sql

I'm a little bit stuck. I have a database table with the following columns:

```
Table Name: Data
*Value
*DateTime
*WeekNumber
*ItemId
*Name
```

I have created the following scripts from which I'd like to place the results into the above table.

```
SELECT D.*, M.Name
FROM
(SELECT SUM (Data) AS [Value],
(SELECT CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE()))) [DateTimeValue], DatePart (Week,TimestampUTC) [WeekNumber], MT.MeterId [MeterID]

FROM DataLog.dl
JOIN MeterTags mt ON dl.MeterTagId = mt.MeterTagId
GROUP BY DatePart (Week,TimestampUTC, dl.MeterTagId, MeterId)
AS D
INNER JOIN Meters m
ON D.MeterId = M.MeterId
ORDER BY MeterId DESC
```

I'm hoping to drop the results from the above query into the corresponding columns in the db table along with creating a new one for MeterID:

```
Value = Value
DateTime = DateTimeValue
WeekNumber = WeekNumber
MeterID = ***Need to create a new column*****
Name = Name
```

I hope this makes sense as I'm pretty inexperienced with SQL and a struggling to get the last pieces put together. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't add a new column during an `INSERT`. You'll have to either add the column, or do your `INSERT` and then `JOIN` the `Meters` table afterward to a select from your `Data` table without it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the standard SQL `INSERT` syntax
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;

what i don't understand is what do you mean by

> MeterID = ***Need to create a new column*****

for more info look 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The existing table doesn't have a column for MeterId so I was wondering is there a way within the syntax to move the data from the query result to the corresponding table columns and create a column in the table called "MeterID"

Comment: no you can't, is against SQL. when adding a column you are using DDL (Data Definition Language), while when inserting rows you are using DML (Data Modification Language). You don't mix them. I suggest you using @grazy syntax

Answer (score 0):

Modify your table and add new column for MeterId.

```
Insert into [Data]
SELECT D.[Value], D.DateTimeValue,D.WeekNumber,MT.MeterId,M.Name
FROM
(SELECT SUM (Data) AS [Value],
(SELECT CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE()))) [DateTimeValue], DatePart (Week,TimestampUTC) [WeekNumber], MT.MeterId [MeterID]

FROM DataLog.dl
JOIN MeterTags mt ON dl.MeterTagId = mt.MeterTagId
GROUP BY DatePart (Week,TimestampUTC, dl.MeterTagId, MeterId)
AS D
INNER JOIN Meters m
ON D.MeterId = M.MeterId
ORDER BY MeterId DESC
```